# Calculation using JSON Data in RecyclerView and ToggleButton

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I want to do calculation using JSON Data in RecyclerView with ToggleButton. When the toggle button is checked the value should change and when its not checked the value should change again for that particular RecyclerView row. The problem is when I click the ToggleButton, 2 other RecyclerView row's ToggleButton is also checked.

CODE:

Activity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GstPlanner extends AppCompatActivity implements GstPlanAdapter.GstPlanListener{
    private static final String TAG = GstPlanner.class.getSimpleName();
    List<String> dateNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    private List<GstPlanList> GSTLisT;
    private GstPlanAdapter mAdapter;
    Context context;
    Spinner ret_pending_drop, state_drop, nil_drop;
    String URL, URL1;
    ProgressBar progress_gst, Progress_Gst_Plan;
    GridLayout grid_gst;
    TextView txt_retry_gst, txt_state_gst, txt_ret_type, txt_final_gst;
    Button btn_retry_gst, btn_submit_state, btn_submit;
    String State_GET;
    RecyclerView recyclerView1;
    RelativeLayout Gst_Plan_Relative;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gst_planner);

        Gst_Plan_Relative = findViewById(R.id.Gst_Plan_Relative);
        recyclerView1 = findViewById(R.id.Recycler_Gst_Plan);
        Progress_Gst_Plan = findViewById(R.id.Progress_Gst_Plan);
        btn_submit_state = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit_state);
        txt_state_gst = findViewById(R.id.txt_state_gst);
        txt_ret_type = findViewById(R.id.txt_ret_type);
        txt_retry_gst = findViewById(R.id.txt_retry_gst);
        btn_retry_gst = findViewById(R.id.btn_retry_gst);
        ret_pending_drop = findViewById(R.id.ret_pending_drop);
        txt_final_gst = findViewById(R.id.txt_final_gst);
        state_drop = findViewById(R.id.state_drop);
        btn_submit = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        nil_drop = findViewById(R.id.nil_drop);
        grid_gst = findViewById(R.id.grid_gst);
        progress_gst = findViewById(R.id.progress_gst);

        GSTLisT = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new GstPlanAdapter(this, GSTLisT, this);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView1.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView1.addItemDecoration(new MyDividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL, 36));
        recyclerView1.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                URL1 = "http://url.com/something.php?state="+state_drop.getSelectedItem().toString()+"&RType="+txt_ret_type.getText().toString()+"&NIL="+nil_drop.getSelectedItem().toString()+"&Month="+ret_pending_drop.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Log.e("URL1",URL1);
                Progress_Gst_Plan.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fetchData();
                GlobalValue.getit = true;
            }
        });

        btn_submit_state.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                URL = "http://url.com/something.php?state="+state_drop.getSelectedItem().toString();
                State_GET = state_drop.getSelectedItem().toString();
                btn_submit_state.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                state_drop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                progress_gst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                fetchMonths();

            }
        });


        btn_retry_gst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                progress_gst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                txt_retry_gst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_retry_gst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btn_submit_state.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                state_drop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

    private void fetchData() {




            JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(URL1,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            if (response == null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't fetch the Details! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                return;
                            }

                            Gst_Plan_Relative.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Progress_Gst_Plan.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                            List<GstPlanList> items = new Gson().fromJson(response.toString(), new TypeToken<List<GstPlanList>>() {
                            }.getType());

                            // adding contacts to contacts list
                            GSTLisT.clear();
                            GSTLisT.addAll(items);


                            // refreshing recycler view
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Progress_Gst_Plan.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error in getting json
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage() +error.getCause());
                    AlertDialog("Error...Please try after some time.");
                    progress_gst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    txt_retry_gst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_retry_gst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btn_submit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Gst_Plan_Relative.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });

            APP.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
        }






    private void fetchMonths() {


        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                    JSONArray arrayContacts = object.getJSONArray("Status");

                    for (int i = 0; i<arrayContacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject contactObject = arrayContacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        dateNames.add(contactObject.getString("Month"));
                    }


                        spinnervalue(dateNames, ret_pending_drop);

                    txt_state_gst.setText(State_GET);
                    progress_gst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    grid_gst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txt_retry_gst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_retry_gst.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btn_submit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                AlertDialog("Error...Please try after some time.");
                progress_gst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                txt_retry_gst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn_retry_gst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btn_submit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            }
        });
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    public void spinnervalue(List<String> value, Spinner spinner1){

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, value);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource
                (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }


    public void AlertDialog(String s) {
        try{
            AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(GstPlanner.this);
            builder1.setMessage(s);
            builder1.setCancelable(true);


            builder1.setPositiveButton(
                    "Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });


            AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
            alert11.show();
        }catch (
                WindowManager.BadTokenException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSubTotalUpdate(int total){
        txt_final_gst.setText(String.valueOf(total));
    }
```

RecyclerView Adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;



public class GstPlanAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GstPlanAdapter.MyViewHolder>
        implements Filterable {
    private Context context;
    private List<GstPlanList> GstPlanList;
    private List<GstPlanList> GstPlanListFiltered;
    private GstPlanListener listener;
    int totalPrice;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView ret_month, due_date, penalty_amt;
        Spinner nil_ret;
        ToggleButton toggleSwitch;



        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);


            ret_month = view.findViewById(R.id.ret_month);
            due_date = view.findViewById(R.id.due_date);
            penalty_amt = view.findViewById(R.id.penalty_amt);
            toggleSwitch = view.findViewById(R.id.switch_gst);

        }
    }


    public GstPlanAdapter(Context context, List<GstPlanList> BiLLList, GstPlanListener listener ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.GstPlanList = BiLLList;
        this.GstPlanListFiltered = BiLLList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent1, int viewType1) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent1.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.gst_plan_view_item_row, parent1, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        final GstPlanList bill = GstPlanListFiltered.get(position);

        holder.nil_ret.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);

        holder.ret_month.setText(bill.getMonth());
        holder.due_date.setText(bill.getDate());

        holder.penalty_amt.setText(bill.getPenatly().toString());

        totalPrice = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < GstPlanList.size(); i++) {
            totalPrice += GstPlanList.get(i).getPenatly();
            countTotal(totalPrice);
        }

        if (GlobalValue.getit == true) {
            if (bill.getNIL().equals("YES")) {
                holder.toggleSwitch.setChecked(true);
                GlobalValue.getit = false;
            } else {
                holder.toggleSwitch.setChecked(false);
                GlobalValue.getit = false;
            }
        }



        holder.toggleSwitch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (holder.toggleSwitch.isChecked()) {

                    int AC = bill.getTODATE();
                    int BC = Integer.parseInt(bill.getNILNO().toString());
                    int ABC = AC * BC;

                    totalPrice = totalPrice - ABC;

                    int A = bill.getTODATE();
                    int B = Integer.parseInt(bill.getNILYES().toString());
                    int AB = A * B;

                    if (AB >= 10000) {
                        holder.penalty_amt.setText("10000");
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + 10000;
                        countTotal(totalPrice);
                    } else {
                        holder.penalty_amt.setText(String.valueOf(AB));
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + AB;
                        countTotal(totalPrice);
                    }

                }
                if (!holder.toggleSwitch.isChecked()) {

                    int AC = bill.getTODATE();
                    int BC = Integer.parseInt(bill.getNILYES().toString());
                    int ABC = AC * BC;

                    totalPrice = totalPrice - ABC;

                    int A = bill.getTODATE();
                    int B = Integer.parseInt(bill.getNILNO().toString());
                    int AB = A * B;
                    if (AB >= 10000) {
                        holder.penalty_amt.setText("10000");
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + 10000;
                        countTotal(totalPrice);
                    } else {
                        holder.penalty_amt.setText(String.valueOf(AB));
                        totalPrice = totalPrice + AB;
                        countTotal(totalPrice);
                    }

                }

            }
        });

    

    }

    public void countTotal(int total){
        listener.onSubTotalUpdate(total);
    }



    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return GstPlanListFiltered.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String charString = charSequence.toString();
                if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                    GstPlanListFiltered = GstPlanList;
                } else {
                    List<GstPlanList> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (GstPlanList row : GstPlanList) {

                        // name match condition. this might differ depending on your requirement
                        // here we are looking for name or phone number match
                        if (row.getDate().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getMonth().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase()) || row.getRType().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())) {
                            filteredList.add(row);
                        }
                    }

                    GstPlanListFiltered = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = GstPlanListFiltered;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                GstPlanListFiltered = (ArrayList<GstPlanList>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

    public interface GstPlanListener {
      //  void onGstPlanSelected(GstPlanList bill);

         void onSubTotalUpdate(int total);
    }


}
```

GstPlanList

```
public class GstPlanList {

    private String RType;
    private String State;
    private String NILNO;
    private String NILYES;
    private String Month;
    private String Date;
    private String NIL;
    private int Penatly;
    private int TODATE;


    public GstPlanList() {
    }

    public Integer getPenatly() {
        return Penatly;
    }

    public int getTODATE() {
        return TODATE;
    }

    public String getNIL() {
        return NIL;
    }

    public String getRType() {
        return RType;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }

    public String getNILNO() {
        return NILNO;
    }

    public String getNILYES() {
        return NILYES;
    }

    public String getMonth() {
        return Month;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return Date;
    }

}
```